# "Report missing imports" even after pip installing the package on my computer

Tags: python, import, python-import, importerror

[The error message when trying to use the package "channels"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TCNo.png)

[I "pip show channels" to make sure that it is already installed on my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUzPL.png)

I faced this problem for every package i "pip install", channels is just one of the examples. Can someone tell me how to solve this problem Thank you T^T

Comment: Rather than having links to screenshots, it's better to either include plain text or show the screenshot inline. In this question, your first screenshot is from your editor and could be shown inline. For the second screenshot, I'd copy the text and insert it using the code sample formatting (

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately pip is extremely temperamental on Windows. For a module to be imported, it needs to be in sys.path.
You have 2 options:

1. Use a Linux VM, which has no pip issues in my experience
   There is an app called Ubuntu on the MS Store
2. Work out where the modules are being installed and in your code, use sys.path.insert() to add the install location to sys.path and then importing.

Hope this helps somewhat :)

Comment: I just realised that you showed a screenshot of command prompt and you could see the install location. Add that location to sys.path specifically